# What is a word for adapting a god into a demi-god or saint?

Tags: single-word-requests, religion

There are words that describe elevating a person into the divine: *apotheosis*, *divinization*, and *deification* as nouns, and *deify* as a verb. In some religions, it is possible for a human to undergo *apotheosis* (like Heracles in ancient Greek mythology); in Catholicism, the terms *deification* and *divinization* (but not *apotheosis*) denote believers acquiring salvation through becoming one with God.

**Is there a single word that denotes the reverse, namely a noun for making a god into a demi-god, saint, or otherwise non-god entity**? For example, pre-exile Israel had widespread polytheism, and books in the Hebrew Bible and Old Testament refer to the worship of multiple gods. [2 Kings 23:14](https://biblehub.com/2_kings/23-14.htm) refers to removing items of worship for Asherah, a goddess who may have at one time been considered a wife to Yahweh ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asherah)). In that case, human (non)believers choose to remove recognition of divine status. Alternatively, there are fictional mythologies where gods are cast down within the mythology, as may have happened with [Aroden](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Aroden) in the Golarion (Pathfinder) mythos. My target word would ideally refer to either situation:

> Asherah underwent _____________ by the time of the Babylonian captivity. She was no longer recognized as a goddess within Judaism.

> Many clerics speculate about the cause of Aroden's _____________ and eventual death.

I can think of one option. The OED attests *[undeify](https://oed.com/view/Entry/211320)*, but *undeification* is unattested in dictionaries I consulted and very rare (about 100 results on Google), so I'd prefer something more common if possible.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mortalize **mortalize** if the god was turned into a mortal, but I don't think that's what you're looking for

Comment: [Religious syncretism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_syncretism) is the general term for the merging of two different religious traditions. This can include the absorption of polytheistic deities into a monotheistic faith, demoting them in the process to mere supernatural creatures or even human saints, but it's a much broader term than what you're looking for I think.

Comment: _Reification_ is a wonderful term that applies here; _reify_ means to re-make, differently. So when _shine_ is made transitive, it's reified and becomes regular: _He shined his shoes_ instead of *_He shone his shoes_. It's a general term and doesn't just apply to gods. Another term, which gods would not approve of, is _repurposing_; when Terry Pratchett invented the goddess Anoia, currently in charge of things getting stuck in drawers, he noted that she is always pictured smoking a cigarette because she used to be a volcano goddess, but she's been repurposed.

Comment: Saints can be _demoted_...could that also apply to gods?

Comment: Christians could argue that going from a pagan god to a Christian saint is a promotion. Others might differ, of course.

Comment: Gradually ignoring some previously worshipped entity does not mean that individual worshippers are "removing divine status" and also does not imply that some "authority" did so. However, what gods so **amongst themselves** is a different matter, as reported by humans. I expect that over time, the importance of this or that god just erodes...no one "removes" their status...their importance just gradually fades away.

Comment: Removing Asherah was restoration of monotheism, not taking away something that was ever officially conferred. The OT is filled with denunciations of false worship, strange fire, and so on. So the entire question here stands on some shaky understanding.

Comment: @FeliniusRex   ...a "restoration"? "Between the 10th century BC and the beginning of their exile in 586 BC, polytheism was normal throughout Israel;[25] it was only after the exile that worship of Yahweh alone became established, and possibly only as late as the time of the Maccabees (2nd century BC) that monotheism became universal among the Jews" But please don't drag me into a religious argument.

Comment: *Reification* and *demotion* are interesting terms here, even if they're more general than what I mean. If there isn't a god-specific term, I'd consider accepting one of those as an answer.

Comment: @Cascabel I am talking about the OT text. Polytheism was frequently, earnestly, and repeatedly condemned from Genesis onward. The Ten Commandments were issued before the entrance into Israel, and they specifically required monotheism. Also, the texts in question never sanctioned any adding-to, so there can be no taking away, because the "adding to" was always condemned as illegitimate. Elevation/demotion of gods require official approval, no? Lastly, if I somehow forced you to reply, I am more powerful than you can even imagine. :)

Comment: ...and I was raised JW for 5 years...what a waste of time.

Comment: John..if you do not mind; I will take your comment and try to expand on it for an alternative viewpoint.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Interesting, but your suggestion does sound a little over-broad in this case; that said, perhaps you could post an answer, or at least suggest an edit to the wiki answer.

Comment: *expropriated*? *co-opted*? *integrated*? *absorbed*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[***demotion***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/demotion)

is a term which has seen  use   when  describing vertical changes in corporate structure  [since at least  the 1880s](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=demote). It has also  seen usage when discussing goddesses (such as ***Asherah***) and their  loss of goddess-hood.

> The biblical passages that best illustrate the ***"demotion"*** of the goddess Asherah to solely an object can be seen in these passages in the book of Kings in which Asherah is referred to in the singular, together with parallel accounts in Chronicles...

[image]

[Congress  Volume Cambridge (1995)](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=cKy9CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA170&dq=Asherah%20demotion&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi62aP7n6HvAhX5RzABHaazCIgQ6AEwA3oECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=Asherah%20demotion&f=false)

---

Eventually [She was seen as a "pole" to be destroyed.](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/702702348100506988/)

[image]

---

From the book [Mother Goddess and other Goddesses...](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=pcwoAAAAYAAJ&q=Asherah%20demotion&dq=Asherah%20demotion&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi62aP7n6HvAhX5RzABHaazCIgQ6AEwBHoECAgQAg)

> ...it may be inaccurate for us to credit
> invading Israelites alone with the ***demotion*** and destruction of goddess religion in Canaan.

[image]

---

More recently...

Many people were  disappointed when  some historically popular  saints were  "demoted" some  50 years ago. Saint Christopher, Valentine, and even Nicholas were demoted. It was suggested that at least one of them had never even existed.

> Once a Saint, always a Saint--kind of, unless you are *demoted*.

[from  this clip at ABCNews](https://abcnews.go.com/International/saint-saint-kind-demoted/story?id=23477573)

Comment: OK...now I am going to try to convert John Lawler's comment into an alternative  answer. This is a very good question, and needs more attention.

Answer (score 2):

How about "relegate"?

> to put someone or something into a lower or less important rank or position:

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/relegate

Comment: _relegate_ is a very good suggestion, but you need to flesh this out a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, [John Lawler](http://formal%20%20%20%20%20%20Make%20(something%20abstract)%20more%20concrete%20or%20real.) said...

***Reification***

> ...is a wonderful term that applies here; reify means to re-make, differently. So when shine is made transitive, it's reified and becomes regular: He shined his shoes instead of *He shone his shoes. It's a general term and doesn't just apply to gods.

[Lexico defines ***reification*** as](https://www.lexico.com/definition/reify) ...

(formal) ***(to) Make (something abstract) more concrete or real.***

> > Another term, which gods would not approve of, is ***repurposing***; when Terry Pratchett invented the goddess Anoia, currently in charge of things getting stuck in drawers, he noted that she is always pictured smoking a cigarette because she used to be a volcano goddess, but she's been...

[***repurposed***](https://www.lexico.com/definition/repurpose).

> Adapt for use in a different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can ‘renounce’ or ‘desanctify’ a former subject of worship.

Demotion is really about downgrading a service rank or a corporate position. It can be applied to a religious figure only as a metaphor.